# Is there a way to mark inbox messages on careers 2.0 as "spam"?

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, spam

I don't want to just hide or delete this particular message. I want to flag it, and the domain it purports to be from, for stackoverflow's staff or some bot to review and block.

I've received an inbox message on careers that is so obviously spam, even I could see it was. They didn't even bother to fix the broken wordpress site that is supposed to represent their fake recruiting company (which was originally skinned as a fake film production company).

Is there AT LEAST a way to block emails from certain domains, or to blacklist them publicly here?

Comment: I'm sure an E-Mail to `careers@stackoverflow.com` will get the matter resolved quickly.

Comment: I sent one alerting them to the spam just before posting this. The point of this post was basically to ask for a feature, which I figured  was more appropriate here, than in a support email.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this Greg.

To block an employer and flag them for us it is a simple, yes, simple* five step process that I've outlined below.

1. Click the reply button on the employer's message.
2. Select "I am not interested".
3. Tell us the reason you're not interested.
4. Check the "Block this employer" checkbox.
5. Click the "Send Message" button.

[image: simple 5 step process]

* could be simpler

Comment: Thanks. I was hesitant to use the "reply" button. So, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Greg: Understood. We agree with you. There's some messaging work coming up and this will be addressed.